# How do I change the time on a Potterton EP 3000 clock?

Tags: heating

I turned the power off and when I turned it back on again, the clock of my Potterton EP3000 was reset, and now the heating comes on at the wrong time. I dont have a manual for it, so I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to change the time on the clock. I've searched the internet for hours and haven't found anything specific to the EP3000.

Comment: A picture might help.

Comment: I have just taken the battery out of my EP3000 and its a Varta Mempac 090 3.6v 100mAh

Answer (score 1):

Having just asked [my own question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10350/potterton-ep3000-horstmann-c27-boiler-programmer-wiring) about an EP3000, I think I know the answer to this one. The current time (and all your programmed on/off times) are preserved during a power outage by a little rechargeable battery that's kept topped up by the mains. But like any rechargeable battery, it's got a finite life. Yours may have died some time ago - you just didn't notice until you switched the power off.

I didn't bother trying to prise the battery out of mine (which is also dead), but based on [this discussion](http://www.diy-forum.net/potterton-ep3000-backup-battery-change-worth-t23046p2.html) it's almost certainly a Varta 250DK. It's an oval about 30x40, 70mm long, containing 8 x 1.2 NiCad cells (9.6 volt total).

You need a bit of confidence (and brute force!) to prise the programmer off its back-plate which is screwed to the wall. It's "half-hinged" on the top, but there's a moulded "retaining latch" on the bottom right. Look from underneath and you'll see a 5mm "slot" about 5cm in from the bottom right. Push a screwdriver **hard** up there to free the latch, and simultaneously pull/prise the bottom edge of the programmer outward and upward.

I can't say exactly where you'll get a replacement (I doubt Varta still make them). The important thing is it should be an 8-cell 9.6v NiCad (don't use Li-ion or whatever). If you take the old one in to Maplin or similar they might be able to supply something compatible.

Other options are: Expensive - pay an electrician/gasman to come and deal with it; Cheap - just live with it and get used to reprogramming the thing whenever you've had a power cut or turned it off for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This may help.  It's not your exact model, it's a 3002.

http://www.heatingcontrolsonline.co.uk/instructions/POTTERTON%20EP2000%20EP2002%20EP3002%20user%20manual.pdf

Comment: The website seems to have moved/removed the PDF you linked to. :(

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question of how to program the controller:

1. Move the slider on the right to the "**clock**" position.
2. Use the **FORWARD** and **REVERSE** buttons to set the time.
3. Use the **DAYS** button to set the day of the week.
4. Move the slider to the **ON 1**, **OFF 1**, **ON 2** and **OFF 2** positions, setting the time for each using the **FORWARD** and **REVERSE** buttons as before.
5. Move the slider to the **AUTO** position to let the unit operate normally.
6. Set the CH and HW sliders to **ONCE** or **TWICE** depending on the times you want them on. (You don't need to set the times for **ON 2** and **OFF 2** if you only have it on once a day.)