# How do I set the clock on a Thermador CT227N or CT227NW oven?

Tags: appliances, oven

The Thermador CT227N and CT227NW oven have a non-discoverable interface for setting the clock time, what is the hidden method to set the time?

Comment: When down voting a question, please suggest how a question might be improved, so we can improve the site.

Comment: This isn't really a home improvement question. It is very localised to one product that is an electrical appliance, and it is easily found by a simple google search or by reading the manual.

Comment: **Operation** of appliances is off-topic; see the [faq#questions] (last bullet point).

Comment: I down voted and voted to close because it is a question about a very specific model of an oven and is something that would likely be found in the manual.  It is unlikely to help anyone else in the future.

Comment: @Steven Thanks for posting your feedback, note that the other question on setting clock was upvoted to 4 and still open, I suggest closing it too since I checked and saw another clock question and on its precedent I posted this one.  http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10089/how-do-i-change-the-time-on-a-potterton-ep-3000-clock

Comment: @Steven Given that over 10,000 people have viewed this question, I'd suggest that this question has been helpful to others.  Perhaps there is another site that this question could be migrated to that is on topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below the clock LED display is a large round knob.  Rotate the knob counter clockwise a couple of whole turns until you hear a beep and the word `time` appears on the display, once you hear the beep, you are setting the time by rotating it clockwise or counter-clockwise to adjust the time shown on the LED display.

When you reach the desired time, press the start button and the clock time is now set to the new time.  You will hear a beep and the word `time` will disappear from the LED display.

Comment: I haven't read the manual to check for the instructions but it can be found at https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1009620/Thermador-Ct127n.html